# Code for finding the vertex normals in Java?

Tags: java, android, objective-c, opengl-es

I have this code in C from this [source](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-4-let.html):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OpenGLCommon.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

    static const Vertex3D vertices[]= {
        {0, -0.525731, 0.850651},             // vertices[0]
        {0.850651, 0, 0.525731},              // vertices[1]
        {0.850651, 0, -0.525731},             // vertices[2]
        {-0.850651, 0, -0.525731},            // vertices[3]
        {-0.850651, 0, 0.525731},             // vertices[4]
        {-0.525731, 0.850651, 0},             // vertices[5]
        {0.525731, 0.850651, 0},              // vertices[6]
        {0.525731, -0.850651, 0},             // vertices[7]
        {-0.525731, -0.850651, 0},            // vertices[8]
        {0, -0.525731, -0.850651},            // vertices[9]
        {0, 0.525731, -0.850651},             // vertices[10]
        {0, 0.525731, 0.850651}               // vertices[11]
    };

    static const GLubyte icosahedronFaces[] = {
        1, 2, 6,
        1, 7, 2,
        3, 4, 5,
        4, 3, 8,
        6, 5, 11,
        5, 6, 10,
        9, 10, 2,
        10, 9, 3,
        7, 8, 9,
        8, 7, 0,
        11, 0, 1,
        0, 11, 4,
        6, 2, 10,
        1, 6, 11,
        3, 5, 10,
        5, 4, 11,
        2, 7, 9,
        7, 1, 0,
        3, 9, 8,
        4, 8, 0,
    };

    Vector3D *surfaceNormals = calloc(20, sizeof(Vector3D));

    // Calculate the surface normal for each triangle

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Vertex3D vertex1 = vertices[icosahedronFaces[(i*3)]];
        Vertex3D vertex2 = vertices[icosahedronFaces[(i*3)+1]];
        Vertex3D vertex3 = vertices[icosahedronFaces[(i*3)+2]];
        Triangle3D triangle = Triangle3DMake(vertex1, vertex2, vertex3);
        Vector3D surfaceNormal = Triangle3DCalculateSurfaceNormal(triangle);
        Vector3DNormalize(&surfaceNormal);
        surfaceNormals[i] = surfaceNormal;
    }

    Vertex3D *normals = calloc(12, sizeof(Vertex3D));
    [result appendString:@"static const Vector3D normals[] = {\n"];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int faceCount = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            BOOL contains = NO;
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                if (icosahedronFaces[(j * 3) + k] == i)
                    contains = YES;
            }
            if (contains)
            {
                faceCount++;
                normals[i] = Vector3DAdd(normals[i], surfaceNormals[j]);
            }
        }

        normals[i].x /= (GLfloat)faceCount;
        normals[i].y /= (GLfloat)faceCount;
        normals[i].z /= (GLfloat)faceCount;
        [result appendFormat:@"\t{%f, %f, %f},\n", normals[i].x, normals[i].y, normals[i].z];
    }
    [result appendString:@"};\n"];
    NSLog(result);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Can some one point me to Java code that does the same thing as above? I would also need to modify it so that it works not just for isohadron but for any vertex array with associated index array.

Comment: The shown algorithm is simple... just consider all faces that are using the vertex, average their normals and re-normalize the result. What is the part you have problems with?

Answer (score 5):

This works for any triangle based mesh.

```
for(int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i += 3)
{
   Vector3 v0 = vertices[indicies[i]].Position;
   Vector3 v1 = vertices[indicies[i+1]].Position;
   Vector3 v2 = vertices[indicies[i+2]].Position;

   Vector3 normal = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(v2 - v0, v1 - v0));

   vertices[indicies[i]].Normal += normal;
   vertices[indicies[i+1]].Normal += normal;
   vertices[indicies[i+2]].Normal += normal;
}
for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
{
   vertices[i].Normal = Vector3.Normalize(vertices[i].Normal);
}
```

Heres a stripped down version of the Vector3 struct

```
public struct Vector3
{
   float X, Y, Z;

   public Vector3(float x, float y, float z)
   {
      X = x; Y = y; Z = z;
   }

   public static Vector3 Cross(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2)
   {
      Vector3 result;
      result.X = (v1.Y * v2.Z) - (v1.Z * v2.Y);
      result.Y = (v1.Z * v2.X) - (v1.X * v2.Z);
      result.Z = (v1.X * v2.Y) - (v1.Y * v2.X);
      return result;
   }
   public static Vector3 Normalize(Vector3 v1)
   {
       float length = v1.X * v1.X + v1.Y * v1.Y + v1.Z * v1.Z;
       length = Math.Sqrt(length);
       v1.X /= length; v1.Y /= length; v1.Z /= length;
   }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Note: That will override normals for neighboring triangles and eventually you'll end up with normals that aren't all perpendicular to the triangle surface.

Comment: Where these classes Vector3d Vector3d.Normalize etc comes from? Are they from some Java library somewhere?

Comment: I think the code for generating normals is ok. I was working with that lately and it was looking verry similiar.. not sure about i+=3 though. WhenI talk about mesh I usually mean triangle strip and there every new index make new triangle.. this works for trinagles and as these don't have to be connected it's strange to use.. not sure how java does this stuff though (using pure openGL)

Comment: @Dave, it doesn't override the normals for neibouring triangles, it calculates the average. This code works for almost any purpose.

Comment: @Alan, I've added a stripped down version of the Vector3 struct I use with only the functions needed for my code sample. I could send you the whole thing, but it's C#. I'm sure your Vector3D type has normalize and cross functions too that you can use.

Comment: @Raven, this of course assumes a triangle list, which is the most commonly used for arbitary models ;).

Comment: The question asks for finding normal per vertex and not normal per triangle or surface. The sample C code in my question calculates normal per vertex. Its very hard to find Java based normal per vertex code on a triangular mesh.On the other hand there are a lot of places that gives normal per surface and I dont need that as I have already done that in Java.

Comment: This finds the normal per vertex! I assume what you want is smooth shading, that's exactly what this code does.

Comment: Pardon me but this is not JAVA as JAVA have no struct, right? I was trying to reproduce this solution but NetBeans 8 is telling me there is no struct, also that Normalize is missing return and that there also is no Math.Sqrt() only Math.sqrt() and it needs to be cast as (float)...? I am asking this as OP was asking for JAVA code...